# commutative law is not derivable in group theory?

Tags: group-theory, logic

This is the last question of my homework. I solved everything else, but this gives me a hard time. Hope my translation is correct and this is the right place for this kind of question.

Show that the commutative law in group theory is not derivable.
A o B = B o A

Comment: Because there are noncommutative groups...

Comment: I Dont think thats the proof my professor is looking for.

Comment: @Christopher it sort of is.  If the commutative law were derivable, then there could be no non-commutative groups.  But [insert your favourite non-abelian group here] exists and is a group, hence the commutative law cannot be derivable

Comment: @Christopher Existence of a model in which commutative law doesn't hold means (group axioms) + (noncommutative) is consistent, so neg(noncommutative) is not derivable from (group axioms).

Comment: Create a counterexample: a group that is not commutative. To be specific: define a domain and an operator in such a way that all the axioms for groups are satisfied (i.e. show that it is a group), but such that the operator is not commutative.

Comment: I thought about a counter example. It would be the easiest way. But my professor was talking about a proof with the Gödel's completeness theorem and now I'm confused and thought that there was a more.... complicated way to show this.

Comment: What have you solved before in your homework for this question? This would help us to know what is expected.

Comment: Try the 3rd dihedral group

Comment: Dietrich Burde I would like too but I need 10 reputation points to post pictures. I dont know a another way.

Comment: I think it's confusing to use "derivable" without clarifying what it means.

Comment: I just copied the question. I know as much as you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible that you've been confused by your professor's hint. Remember that Godel's completeness theorem, when phrased as an if-and-only-if, has two parts:

- If $T$ is consistent, then $T$ has a model.
- If $T$ has a model, then $T$ is consistent.

The first of these is **completeness**, and the second is **soundness**. But since soundness is vastly easier to prove - to the point of bordering on trivial - the whole biconditional is often just called "completeness."

And this bit of abuse-of-terminology may have mislead you as to the complexity of the problem: **it's soundness that you want here**. Specifically, suppose you want to show that $T\not\vdash\varphi$. This is the same as showing that $T\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ is consistent, which by soundness will follow from the existence of a model of $T\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$. Which is a long-winded way of saying:

> It suffices to show that there is such a thing as a non-abelian group.